# How to use Facebook or Google issued Oauth 2 tokens to access spring boot protected resources

Tags: facebook, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am using spring boot& angular4 and mysql to develop my application. Now i would like to use facebook and Google to authenticate my users and then use it's  access tokens to access my protected resources. Please help me on this.

Comment: There are like, a thousand tutorials available for this on the internet, including spring's own.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked these links

**SPRING SOCIAL FACEBOOK**

https://www.ximedes.com/spring-social-facebook-tutorial/

**Google Sign-In and Spring Boot**

https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-with-google-sign-in-in-spring-boot

Let us know if your are looking for any specific scenario otherwise.

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply @Mahesh_loya. I am looking for specific use-case. I am having Angular 7 web application & mobile apps  taking to my spring boot REST API. I deployed UI and back-end into separate servers and using micro services architecture. So please give me an idea to implement SSO using google and facebook.